# What's $P(E)$ if you know $P(E|A)$ and $P(E|A^c)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

***If I know*** :

$P(A) = 1/3$

$P(B) = 1/2$

$P(C) = 1/3$

$P(E|A) = 2/3$

$P(E|A^c) = 1/4$

***How do I calculate $P(E)$ ?***

This is my incorrect solution :

$P(E\cap A)$ = $P(E|A)$ ⋅ $P(A)$ = $2/9$

$P(E\cap A^c)$ = $P(E|A^c)$ ⋅ $P(A^c)$ = $1/6$

$P(E) = P(E|A) ⋅ P(E\cap A) + P(E|A^c) ⋅  P(E\cap A^c) = 3/8$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is the last formula what you actually meant to write?

Comment: A version of the *law of total probability* states for events $A$ and $E$ in $\Omega$, that $P(E)=P(E|A)P(A)+P(E|A^c)P(A)$. This is wonderfully useful.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 $A^c$ instead of the last $A$ right?

Comment: @Konstantin Yes, in the second term, it should be $P(A^c)$, not $P(A)$.

Comment: @Konstantin yes, sorry i thought i caught that but i’ve missed my 5 minute window to edit the comment. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability): 
$$
P(E)= P(E\cap A) + P(E\cap A^c) = P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|A^c)P(A^c) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{3} =\frac{7}{18}. 
$$

Comment: How do I know I can use the law of total probability to calculate $P(E)$?

Comment: @FBIT You can use the law of total probability to calculate $P(E)$ because the assumption for the theorem is met: (measurable) sets $A$ and $A^c$ form pairwise disjoint events whose union will give you back the entire sample space. Since the condition is met, you can use this theorem.

Comment: Why $P(E)$ can't depend by one more event from a different sample space?

Comment: @FBIT I am not sure if I am answering your question. But in general, if $A_1, A_2, A_3,\ldots$ are pairwise disjoint (measurable) events whose union is the entire sample space, then $P(E)= P(E\cap A_1)+ P(E\cap A_2)+P(E\cap A_3)+\ldots $. Now, if you have the additional information $P(A_i)$ and $P(E|A_i)$ for each $i\geq 1$, then the above equation can be reformulated as $P(E)=P(E|A_1)P(A_1)+P(E|A_2)P(A_2)+P(E|A_3)P(A_3)+\ldots$. In your example above, the information $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ are extra information that you don't really need to figure out $P(E)$.

Comment: Why the probability of the entire sample space is $7/6$ and not $6/6 = 1 $?

Comment: @FBIT The probability of the entire sample space should be $1$. When you consider $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$, you get $7/6$. This shows that the sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ are not pairwise disjoint sets (two of the sets have a nonempty intersection). So the sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ do not partition the sample space. The definition of a partitioning of a set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Answer (score 0):

Use $P(E) = P((E \cap A) \cup (E \cap A^c))$ and proceed with disjointness of $E \cap A$ and $E \cap A^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $E\cap A\subseteq A$, $E\cap A^c\subseteq A^c$, so $(E\cap A)\cap(E\cap A^c)=\emptyset$. And $(E\cap A)\cup(E\cap A^c)=E\cap(A\cup A^c)=E$. So $$P(E)=P(E\cap A)+P(E\cap A^c)=P(E|A)P(A)+P(E|A^c)P(A^c)$$

Answer (score 0):

You're all right up to the last line. But then you should use $P(E) = P(E \cap A) + P(E \cap A^c)$ because $E$ is the disjoint union of $E \cap A$ and $E \cap A^c$, and probabilities of disjoint unions sum. There's no reason to multiply again by $P(E|A)$ and $P(E|A^c)$.